# Dynamic source data for powerpoint chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

[image]

The data on the chart on the powerpoint slide is dependent on the data encased by the blue lines. The data is on a worksheet that pops out when i click edit data after right clicking on the chart.

I am trying to write a vba code to set the source of the data to include all of the data but to no avail as of now. My code is as follows:

```
Melon.Chart.SetSourceData _
Source:=Melon.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B3:C" & (28 + Weekno))
```

Melon is the name of the chart on the powerpoint slide. Weekno actually stands for the week number of the 2017 which is a variable depending on the current week. The above code keeps returning a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch error and does not set the source data to the intended range.

Anyone has any idea? All help will be appreciated! Thank you!

[image: Error is for the last line of code]

[image: Error is for the last line of code]

Comment: How is `Weekno` defined? Is it a numeric type like `Integer` or `Long`? What value does it have when you run the code? Could you post the rest of the code?

Comment: Try this instead: Melon.Chart.SetSourceData _
Source:=Melon.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B3:C" & Cstr(28 + Weekno)))

Comment: @RyanWildry `Weekno` is an `Integer`. I have attached my codes for your reference. Thank you.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thank you Steve. I have implemented your recommendation and I attached a screenshot of the result.

Comment: 'With Melon.Chart.ChartData
    .Activate
   .Workbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range("$A$1:$C$29")

End With'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Melon.Chart.ChartData
    .Activate
   .Workbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range("$A$1:$C$29")

End With
```

This Works!!!! Im so happy